# Haskell compression on list of lists

Tags: haskell

I imagined the following code:

```
compress :: [[a]] -> [(Int,a)]
compress  [[]] = []
compress  [(x:xs)] = (1 + length (takeWhile x xs), x) : compress [(dropWhile x xs)]
```

I want to count each element in a list of lists. There are identical elements in each list, for example: 
`[[1,1,1], [2,2]]`.

I can only achieve the following output:

`[(1,[1,1,1]), (1,[2,2])]`

, but what I really need is this:

`[(3,1), (2,2)]`.

I can't get deep enough to count the element in each list and probably made it more complicated with takeWhile dropWhile, hence each list has the same element in it.

Comment: Are you sure you want `[[a]] -> [(Int,a)]`, not `[a] -> [(Int,a)]`? The former (if the inner lists are already homogeneous groups) would actually be much easier.

Comment: If a is a list then [a] would be good, but - if I am correct - in this way I can't assume it has more than one list in the list. So yeah I am positive it is that way.

Comment: Can any of the interior lists be empty? `map (length &&& head)` would work otherwise. (Actually, a better question is what *would* you do if a list were empty? You can't produce an arbitrary value of type `a` for the output in that case.) (`&&&` is imported from `Control.Arrow`)

Comment: Basically i think the type signature is right. You may try something like `map ((,) <$> length <*> head) :: [[a]] -> [(Int, a)]`.

Comment: Yes the list can be empty, all I care about is that I can count the elements inside the list.

Comment: Like I said in my updated comment, what will you do if a list is empty? `compress [[1,1,1], []] == [(3,1), (0,???)]`.

Comment: Then it is not in the list. [[1,1,1], []] == [(3,1)]

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each sublist contains one unique element, or just that the output only reflects the ones that do. That is, does `compress [[1,1,1], [1,2]]`  produce `[(3,1)]`, or is it undefined?

Comment: It is undefined, because all the lists have identical elements or none at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to

1. Filter out empty lists
2. Apply `length` and `head` to the remaining lists
3. Collect the results in the final output.

`Control.Arrow` provides a useful operator `&&&` which, when specialized to functions, looks like

```
f &&& g = \x -> (f x, g x)
```

With that, you can simply write

```
compress = map (length &&& head) . filter (not . null)
```

Using a list comprehension, it's just

```
compress xs = [(length x, y) | x@(y:_) <- xs]
```

The pattern match implicitly filters out the empty lists while extracting the first element without a call to `head`.

Comment: I hate seeing beginners pointed to `head` or the general "look, then leap" style. That's idiomatic for Lisp, but widely discouraged in Haskell. The list comprehension version is much nicer; another option is to use `mapMaybe` with either `uncons` or `headMay`. Separately, it should be noted that these both calculate lengths lazily, which probably won't cause a space leak in likely applications but still seems a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a better fit for a folding job since conditionally you will drop some of the sublists (ie when `length` is 0). One approach could be

```
Prelude> let comp = foldr (\s r -> if null s then r else (length s, head s):r) []
Prelude> comp [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[],[5,5,5,5,5,5]]
[(3,1),(3,2),(6,5)]
```

Comment: `length s == 0` is O(n) in the length of the list, and strict in its spine; `null s` is O(1) and only examines the first cons/nil constructor. This was something I expected to be lazier as a beginner—so, for the curious, if you want lazy behaviour from the first expression (e.g. an analogue of `length xs < 3` that only examines at most 3 constructors) then you need to use `genericLength s == (0 :: Nat)` with a lazy number type like `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` (with an appropriate `instance Num`); unfortunately this is neither very efficient nor very idiomatic.

Comment: @Jon Purdy Very good comment. Thanks for pointing out will. I correct acordingly.